# All user's sessions reset in browser after updating classes in ASP.net server

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, session

Every time I rewrite any class (App_Code folder) and update it on my server, all sessions in the website resets in everybody's browsers.
I have a ASP.net website that I change code in it frequently and when it comes to classes in the App_Code folder, for some reason it decides to reset all the sessions including the user's login. So it happens that after I update the classes (any class) all the users log out automatically and then they have to login all over again. Can you please help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you must keep session around, try using a non in memory store.  Like sql server . https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state

Comment: @granadaCoder that looks like a lot of stuff to do. Oh well, looks like I have no choice :P thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Session to survive a restart/reset (which is triggered by your code update), you need to move session to a more permanent storage mechanism.

The most usual suspect is to use a database storage, and most usual'er is Sql Server.

See:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state

If that link dies, you can just internet-search

```
<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString=""
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />
```

Comment: All of this is pretty confusing to me. Does writing the following code is enough to make it work? Or do I need to create a new table in the database? Or any other actions?

Comment: The Microsoft article describes it with more clarity than I ever could. I gave you the reason ~why~ you lose session (reset/restart). and a possible way to overcome it. Follow the ms article verbatim. The above code is simply a way to FIND the full instructions, it is NOT the full instructions.